# Proof that the function on $C[0,b]$ is a contraction

Tags: integration, general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

**Question** **:**

Let  $a$,$b$  be  real  numbers  with  $0\lt b\lt 1$ . Consider  the  subset  $X\subset C[0,b]$  consisting  of  the  functions  $f$  s.t $f(0)=a$ .Then  $X$  is  closed  in  $C[0,b]$.  Define , $$Tf(x) := a+\int_0^x  |f(t)|dt ,(0\le x\le b).$$

Prove  that $T$  is    contraction **of** **$x$** and  there  is  a  *unique*  $f\in X$  satisfying  $$f'=|f| $$  on  $(0,b)$

**My**  **attempt** **:**

$$T \ :\ X\subset C[0,b]  \rightarrow \mathbb R$$
 To  prove  contraction ,  I  have  to  show $$|Tf(x)-Tg(x)|\lt ||f(x)-g(x)||_{\infty}$$  where  $||\ .\ ||_{\infty}$  is  the  *supremum*  *norm*  on  $C[0,b]$.

$$|Tf(x)-Tg(x)|=|(\int_0^x |f(t)|dt-\int_0^x |g(t)|dt)|$$
$$= |\int_0^x(|f(t)|-|g(t)|)dt\ \  |$$
$$\le |\ \int_0^x |f(t)-g(t)|dt\ |$$
$$\le \int_0^x |f(t)-g(t)|dt $$
$$\le sup_{t\in [0,x]} |f(t)-g(t)|.x$$ 
$$\lt ||f(t)-g(t)||_\infty ;\ \ as\ \ x\le b\lt 1\ $$

So  this  is  a  *contraction* .  But  I  don't  know  what  "*contraction*  *of*  *x*  "  means .

As  for  the  second  part  ,  by  *Banach*  *Contraction*  *Principle*   , there  is  a  $f\in X$  s.t  $$f(x)=a+\int_0^x  |f(t)|dt,(0\le x\le b)$$
 $$or \ \ ,\ \ f'(x)=|f(x)|$$

Is  my  proof  allright  $?$

I  am  a  little  skeptical  about  the  last  step  ,if  it  is  correct  or  not  . Correct  me  if  I  have  made  other  mistakes  also.

Thanks  for  any  help.

Comment: The last step is alright, but you have not yet shown that $f$ is unique.

Comment: Will that be contraction of $X$ instead of contraction of $x$?

Comment: You need to show that $\exists \lambda < 1$ such that $\|T(f) - T(g)\| \leq \lambda \|f-g\|$ for all $f,g\in X$.

Comment: This is a typo, it should be *contraction of $X$*.

Comment: @JohnMa :    . As  the  book  has  it  printed ,  it  is _contraction_  _of_  _$x$_  . .  That  is  a  point  of  confusion.